# html5/jquery validations not working for jquery input mask

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I have used a jQuery plugin for masked input in my form for the contact field. The plugin works just fine, its just that i'm not able to validate that particular field (contact field) either by HTML5 validations or jQuery validations.

The problem is that the Contact input field is getting submitted even on empty input box. Its simply not able to identify it as a `required` field in `HTML5`, using 'jQuery validations' also results the same. I guess there's some kind of a conflict between `jQuery Masked Input` and `HTML5/jQuery validations`.

My code is like this:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="registration_form">

   <div class="container">

      <div class="div_left">Name <span class="red">*</span>   
           <input type="text" name="name" class="input_form" placeholder="Enter your Name" required>
      </div><br>
      <div class="div_left">Email <span class="red">*</span>   
           <input type="email" name="email" class="input_form" placeholder="Enter your Email" required>
      </div><br>
      <div class="div_left">Contact No. <span class="red">*</span>
           <input type="text" name="contact" class="input_form" class="required" id="jqxmaskedinput" required>
      </div><br>
      <div class="div_left">Nationality <span class="red">*</span>  
           <input type="text" name="nationality" class="input_form" placeholder="Enter your Nationality" required>
      </div><br>

   </div>

</div>
```

Used this jquery as suggested by the plugin

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqxcore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqxmaskedinput.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Create jqxMaskedInput
        $("#jqxmaskedinput").jqxMaskedInput({ width: '308px', height: '23px', mask: '##########' });

    });
</script>
```

Please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried using jqxValidator?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var inputToMask = $("#jqxmaskedinput");
    // Create jqxMaskedInput
    inputToMask.jqxMaskedInput({ width: '308px', height: '23px', mask: '##########' });

    $('#registration_form').on('submit', function() {
        if ( $.trim(inputToMask.val()) == "") {
            alert ("empty field");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i tried but its not working .. the input field is still submitting blank

Comment: Ok, Please create a fiddle where we can debug it real time for you.